Cannot connect to the minikube backend service
So, i have spent fine amount of time could not find the solution.
Scenario: I was playing around with minikube. I have 3 services. One is mysql, another frontend and then another is springboot backend.
While my mysql service is up i can access the mysql from the bin/bash also with port-forwarding as well.
The issue is when i try to access my backend-service using this url minikube-ip:nodePort/backend-app/api/v1
E.g. 192.168.49.2:32500/backend-app/api/v1
It does not response.
ok.
I have checked the logs for my backend app it just starts normally as usualy. No errors, even i have a endpoint which does not fires any query, it just does not responds to that endpoint as well.
So, my guess is somehow i am unable to reach the backend-service.
I can access the apis though from the minikube enbironment using minikube ssh.
I have cross checked my minikube ip and the nodePort that i have defined all are ok.

I have reinstalled the minikube with
minikube install --vm-driver=hyperkit
resolved the issue.
I have previously installed the minikube without specifying the vm driver adn thus unable to ping the minikube ip.
So , the issue was not being able to ping the minikube ip, however with port-forwarding i was able to ping it.
Now, with the current installation and i can ping the minikube ip as well not need any port forwarding.
